# How to direct the compiler to overload the function with the default argument?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>       
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
//EDIT:    
vector<float> data={1.1f,2.2f,3.3f};
float getData(int index=1) { return data[index]; }
vector<float> getData() { return data; }

void main(){
  auto d=getData(); //will assign {1.1f,2.2f,3.3f} to d;
  for (auto x : d) cout << x << " "; cout << "\n";
}
```

How can it be modified to get only the 2nd element of data[3], i.e., 2.2f?

ps.
It compiled by
[image]

Comment: `auto d = getData()[1]` ?

Comment: `getData()` is ambigious so I would remove the default argument - or give the functions different names. Note: `void main()` is invalid. It should be `int main()`

Comment: Do NOT use `using namespace std;`, your code is broken in C++17 after addition of [std::data](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/data) which you happen to include.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want. Do you want `d` to be a vector with 3 elements all equal `2.2f`?

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo, just found to pass "the compiler in VS Community 2019" by "vector" instead of "float".

Comment: @Quimby, Great tips. Totally agree to have good habit. I will remember from now now.

Comment: What overload are you expecting to be called in `auto d=getData();`? The compiler  has no idea. It sees two overloads that looks equally ok, so which one should it pick? It can't, so compilation fails.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo, the purpose of the test is to check my compiler overloading directions.

Comment: @Serge Ballesta, note that the calling getData()[1] will not enter getData(int index=1).

Comment: Ok. It seems your compiler is doing at least one thing correctly by refusing to compile this.

Comment: Yes, that is right. It is a bad trial.

Comment: I'm a bit lost. What is the goal? Do you want to make your code compilable? If so, just remove the default argument or change the name of one of the functions. And make it `int main()` instead of `void main()`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question since you haven't clarified what you hope to achieve.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo, yes, please. I would like to delete, but it might be a waste for the useful comments. I should have thought more carefully before ask this question.

Comment: @MathArt Questions without answers are usually not very helpful. If you don't plan on clarifying the question, I think it's best removed.